# Sorting an array with duplicate values without modifying the elements, without using secondary array or without using any inbuilt function

Tags: arrays, c, sorting

So as the question says i am just trying to sort an array with duplicate values.
The array is sorted properly but problem arises when a duplicate value is given to the array

O/P:without duplicate

> ```
> Enter the size of the array : 5
> Enter the 5 elements
> 7 3 4 8 1
> After sorting: 1 3 4 7 8 
> Original array value 7 3 4 8 1
> ```

O/P: with duplicates

> ```
> 5 3 1 1 4
> After sorting: 1 3 4 1 3 
> Original array value 5 3 1 1 4
> ```

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print_sort(int *arr, int size) //function definition
{
    int i, j, k, temp, largest = arr[0], smallest = arr[0];
    for( i = 1 ; i < size ; i++ )
    {
        if(arr[i] > largest)
        {
            largest = arr[i];
        }
        if(arr[i] < smallest)
        {
            smallest = arr[i];
        }
    }
    printf("After sorting: ");
    for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        temp = largest;
        printf("%d ", smallest);
        for(k = i + 1; k < size; k++)
        {
            if(arr[i] == arr[k])
            {
                smallest = arr[i];
                break;
            }
            for(j = 0; j < size; j++)
            {
                if(arr[j] > smallest && arr[j] < temp)
                {
                    temp = arr[j];
                }
            }
            smallest = temp;
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
    printf("Original array value ");
    for( i = 0 ; i < size ; i++ )
    {
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int size, i;
    printf("Enter the size of the array : ");
    scanf("%d", &size);
    int arr[size];
    printf("Enter the %d elements\n",size);
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
    }
    print_sort(arr, size);
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Did you try to look up for existing well-known sorting algorithms? Instead of some home-brew one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand that it is a specific exercise (homework ?), with no possibility to modify the array not to use an additional array.

This implies that classical sorting algorithms cannot work.

Iteratively searching for the minimum is a possible solution, even if not efficient O(n^2).

To cope with duplicates, it it necessary not only to memorize the current minimum, but also its position.

This is a possible implementation.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void print_sort(int *arr, int size) //function definition
{
    int i, j, k, largest = arr[0], smallest = arr[0];
    int i_smallest = 0;
    for (i = 1; i < size; i++ ) {
        if (arr[i] > largest) {
            largest = arr[i];
        }
        if(arr[i] < smallest) {
            smallest = arr[i];
            i_smallest = i;
        }
    }
    printf("After sorting: ");
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        int temp = largest + 1;
        int i_temp = -1;
        printf("%d ", smallest);
        if (i == size-1) break;
        for (k = 0; k < size; k++) {
            if (arr[k] < smallest) continue;
            if (arr[k] == smallest) {
                if (k <= i_smallest) continue;
                i_temp = k;
                temp = smallest;
                break;
            }
            if (arr[k] < temp) {
                temp = arr[k];
                i_temp = k;
            }
        }
        smallest = temp;
        i_smallest = i_temp;
    }
    printf("\n");
    
    printf("Original array value ");
    for( i = 0 ; i < size ; i++ )
    {
        printf("%d ",arr[i]);
    }
}

int main(void) {
    int size, i;
    printf("Enter the size of the array : ");
    if (scanf("%d", &size) != 1) exit(1);
    int arr[size];
    printf("Enter the %d elements\n",size);
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (scanf("%d", &arr[i]) != 1) exit(1);
    }
    print_sort(arr, size);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yeah its a homework. Thank you so much for your answer. I thought of using the index values but i just didn't know how to implement it.

Comment: If this answer is OK, could you please accept it? (but take time to check it before...).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is easier to insert each read value directly into the sorted Array. So you don't have to sort the array afterwards.
If you want to do it this way, geeksforgeeks.org has nice examples also for C which I already used (https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/search-insert-and-delete-in-a-sorted-array/).

```
// C program to implement insert operation in
// an sorted array.
#include <stdio.h>

// Inserts a key in arr[] of given capacity. n is current
// size of arr[]. This function returns n+1 if insertion
// is successful, else n.
int insertSorted(int arr[], int n, int key, int capacity)
{
    // Cannot insert more elements if n is already
    // more than or equal to capacity
    if (n >= capacity)
        return n;

    int i;
    for (i = n - 1; (i >= 0 && arr[i] > key); i--)
        arr[i + 1] = arr[i];

    arr[i + 1] = key;

    return (n + 1);
}

/* Driver program to test above function */
int main()
{
    int arr[20] = { 12, 16, 20, 40, 50, 70 };
    int capacity = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
    int n = 6;
    int i, key = 26;

    printf("\nBefore Insertion: ");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);

    // Inserting key
    n = insertSorted(arr, n, key, capacity);

    printf("\nAfter Insertion: ");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I understand that the problem has an artificial constraint: we cannot modify the input array. To be confirmed by OP ...

Comment: Yeah we cannot modify the input array